# Smooth transition between html pages with a loading image animation

Tags: jquery, transition

This is excatly what I'm looking for: http://hoverstud.io
. I'm NOT looking for something like this-> http://bit.ly/11jdunO , which has too many issues and bugs.

Can someone please help me find a tutorial or some links?

Comment: What language and environment are you using?

Comment: Simple Pages using HTML and CSS

Comment: You could fade out your `body` when clicking on a link, then redirect, then fade in the `body` of the new page. Is that what you want ?

Comment: Yup. If you have visited the second link I mentioned, It almost has  the same code you have given and has some erros like flickering once and loading multiple times etc. I really needed something like the example site I had given. I have seen sites using #! techniques in the url. I don't know why they use it. But almost all those sites use pretty ajax kind of transitions.

Comment: Any idea how the first page does it? Id really like to know

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure of what you exactly want but you could use such a code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // to fade in on page load
    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(400); 
    // to fade out before redirect
    $('a').click(function(e){
        redirect = $(this).attr('href');
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').fadeOut(400, function(){
            document.location.href = redirect
        });
    });
})
```

It will fade the entire page. If you want to fade just a part of your page, change `body` by whatever you want.

Comment: Almost got the solution. Sharing it here > http://blog.cergis.com/posts/11/html5-history-api

Answer (score 7):

I would utilize a few newer and cleaner tools for this.
Nowadays you can use CSS transitions to do this.

Here's a very simple example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .container {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 1s;
      }

      .container-loaded {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- All the content you want to fade-in here. -->
    </div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.container').addClass('container-loaded');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm assuming here that the transition between pages is a full page reload, so the `container-loaded` class is gone once the page reloaded.

But it should be almost trivial to implement this for one-page web apps using any popular framework, [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) or anything like that.

More things to note:

- If you want to wait until the page images are loaded as well, you could use `document.onload` instead of `$(document).ready()`.
- It would be almost as easy to implement without using jQuery, if [`document.querySelector`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) and [classLists](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist) are available for you.

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for, TYVM for the info.

Comment: Could you please paste working example. I tried: http://wklej.org/id/1635681/ but nothing ever happens when I go to another website.

Comment: If you'll excuse my overly long delay, here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n0b7w5bq/

Comment: Kudos on adding the css class to avoid awkward FOUT

Answer (score 2):

I built something like this.

First place a #preloader on the HTML on a div like this

```
<div id="preloader"></div>
```

If you want to, you can place a gif inside to.

Then setup some CSS:

```
#preloader {
        background: #FFF;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
```

Now make some script like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
     $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
});

$('a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     t = $(this).attr('href');
     $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeIn('slow',function(){
          window.location.href = t;
     });
});
```

And you are done :)

The first part is to make your preloader appear when the window is loading, and then fadeOut.

The second is to bind a click on the archor to fadeIn the preloader and redirect to the href of the archor.